# multiple CData to a single one

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I am trying to create an xml by transforming another xml using xslt.
the problem is: I am using multiple "xsl:value of select=...." in a single element, and I marked that element as a CData element. The value that I receive after the transformation includes multiple CData, while I want them all to be within a single CData.

for example:
original xml:

```
<test>
    <text1>WOW</text1>
    <text3>NO</text3>
</test>
```

xslt (there are headers above to have "Bla" value as CData):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="Bla" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Bla id="bla">
            text<xsl:value-of select="test/text1" />moreText<xsl:value-of select="test/text3" />
        </Bla>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Bla id="bla"><![CDATA[text]]><![CDATA[WOW]]><![CDATA[moreText]]><![CDATA[NO]]></Bla>
```

But, What I want to get in the end is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Bla id="bla"><![CDATA[textWOWmoreTextNO]]></Bla>
```

Anyone knows what I need to change to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? Have you tried to define the element with e.g. `<Bla id="bla"><xsl:value-of select="concat('text', test/text1, 'moreText', test/text3)"/></Blah>`? But your result is odd, which XSLT processor does that?

Comment: I tried it with both my java code (using the javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory) and by using Altova XMLSpy.

Comment: also, the example you gave me works great!
if there won't be a better solution. I will use it.
Thanks :)

Comment: I have written an answer that you should be able to accept so that this question can be closed properly.

Comment: I am still trying to implement your solution. when Ill be successful, I will close the question. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example with Saxon 6.5.5 and Saxon 9.5, they both output a single CDATA section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Bla id="bla"><![CDATA[
            textWOWmoreTextNO]]></Bla>
```

and at least for XSLT 2.0 I think that http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#serdm with "For each subsequence of adjacent text nodes in S5, copy a single text node to the new sequence equal to the values of the text nodes in the subsequence concatenated in order. Any text nodes with values of zero length are dropped." prescribes that the the adjacent text nodes created should be merged and then with `cdata-section-elements` for serialization you should get a single CDATA section. If the XSLT processor you use does not do that then file a bug on it, as a workaround try to create a single text with `xsl:value-of select="concat(...)"`, e.g. `<Bla id="bla"><xsl:value-of select="concat('text', test/text1, 'moreText', test/text3)"/></Blah>`.